# Solution article not updating using FresDesk API "PUT" method

Tags: c#, article, freshdesk

I am using C# to create a program that will automatically update a Freshdesk solution article but when I run my code, it runs through without exception but doesnt update the article.  Can anyone tell me where im going wrong?

```html
apiPath = $"/api/v2/solutions/articles/{articleID}";

string publishArticle = "{\"description\" : \"publish article\", \"status\" : 2}";

                request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + fdDomain + ".freshdesk.com" + apiPath);
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "PUT";
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publishArticle);
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;


                using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through debug and inspecting the results line by line to verify each step is doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: getting the following errors/exceptions in the Length/Position/ReadTimeout/WriteTimeout properties of my "dataStream" object:

+  Length '((System.Net.RequestStream)dataStream).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' long {System.NotSupportedException}

+  Position '((System.Net.RequestStream)dataStream).Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' long {System.NotSupportedException}

Comment: +  ReadTimeout 'dataStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' int {System.InvalidOperationException}

+  WriteTimeout 'dataStream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' int {System.InvalidOperationException}